# Running Integration tests throwing Circular Dependency in CE246

Tags: integration-test, magento2.4.6

Facing circular dependency when running tests `../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose --debug`

```
Test 'Magento\AdminGws\Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\ControllerTest::testCreateShippingForOrderCreatedInAllowedStore' started
Unable to revert fixture: Magento/Sales/_files/order_on_second_website.php
#0 /var/www/html/mage-live/magento/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/AdminGws/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/ControllerTest.php(68): Magento\AdminGws\Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\ControllerTest->testCreateShippingForOrderCreatedInAllowedStore()

Caused By: Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config depends on Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool and vice versa.
```

Coverage and testSuite is normal, just removed `.dist` extension from `phpunit.xml` file.

```
<coverage>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../../app/code/Magento</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../../lib/internal/Magento</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory>../../../app/code/*/*/Test</directory>
            <directory>../../../lib/internal/*/*/Test</directory>
            <directory>../../../lib/internal/*/*/*/Test</directory>
            <directory>../../../setup/src/*/*/Test</directory>
        </exclude>
    </coverage>
    <!-- Test suites definition -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Magento Integration Tests">
            <file>testsuite/Magento/IntegrationTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
        <!-- Memory tests run first to prevent influence of other tests on accuracy of memory measurements -->
        <testsuite name="Memory Usage Tests">
            <file>testsuite/Magento/MemoryUsageTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Magento Integration Tests Real Suite">
            <directory>testsuite</directory>
            <directory>../../../app/code/*/*/Test/Integration</directory>
            <exclude>testsuite/Magento/MemoryUsageTest.php</exclude>
            <exclude>testsuite/Magento/IntegrationTest.php</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```